# Version tags for [actionscript], [actionscript-2] and [actionscript-3]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [actionscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) tag is ambiguous at the moment. It could either mean ActionScript 1, ActionScript 2, or ActionScript 3. And in the future, if that ever happens ActionScript 4 (not likely I think but it might).

There's a vast difference in these languages however. ActionScript 1 doesn't know what a class is. ActionScript 2 does, but you can't reattach anything to the screen once you've removed it. In ActionScript 3 you can do that, but you need to create specific event listeners instead of simply defining an object's `onEnterFrame` function.

There's clearly a lot of difference in display-related code for ActionScript. And since ActionScript is used for Flash, it's very likely that a piece of code does display related things. (If you wanted to compute something, surely you'd use a different language...)

Is there even a reason for [actionscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) to exist? Should it be split into [actionscript-1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-1), [actionscript-2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-2), [actionscript-3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3)? (Also, AS1 is just dead today, but some people are still forced to use AS2).

Answer (score 3):

I agree.  The [actionscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) tag should be removed from all questions currently using it.

There are currently seven questions, and they all are tagged [actionscript-3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) as well.  There are twenty-two [actionscript-3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) questions that are not tagged [actionscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript).  This seems quite feasible and the lowest cost way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing devil's advocate here...

No. [actionscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) should not be removed. Do we really want to go down the road of having separate version tags for languages? I believe the common practice on SO is to add version specific tags alongside the more general tag when there are major differences between the versions. However, that is a bit of a nightmare to maintain. I believe the correct thing to do is synomize the version specific tags to the master tag. [This is what was done with the Java8 tag](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1561/41243).

Comment: But the languages are vastly different. The entire display engine is rewritten. Imagine AWT, swing and JavaFX were built into the language... AS1 = AWT, AS2 = swing, AS3 = JavaFX. And everyone has their imports hardcoded.

Comment: @Pimgd, you're the domain expert here. I was literally just playing devil's advocate for the sake of discussion. I personally think you made a compelling case.